# Cmake not finding Qwtplot3D during install

Tags: c++, gnuradio

When trying to install gr-inspector from git hub I get the following error during the cmake process:

> CMake Error at
>   /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148
>   (message):   Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QWTPLOT3D_INCLUDE_DIR
>   QT_QWTPLOT3D_LIBRARY)   (found suitable version "4.8.6", minimum
>   required is "4.2.0") Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388
>   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>   /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1333
>   (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)   CMakeLists.txt:152
>   (find_package)

QT4 and QTPLOT3D are both dependencies for gr-inspector. I'm not quite sure which dependency this issue is linked to.